# recyclerview sometimes get data on scroll, sometimes not

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that gets the first 10 items, when I scroll it down sometimes it gets the others, sometimes not:

```
item 22
item 21
item 20
item 19
item 18
item 17
item 16
item 15
item 14
item 13
usually it stops at item 13. (not getting the onscroll items)
```

but sometimes it works and get the others (12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1...)

my scroll code:

```
  recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                    getData();
                }
            }
        });
```

get data:

```
 private void getData() {
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount, user_id));
    }
```

getdata server

```
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(String requestCount, String user_id) {
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    requestCount = requestCount + "&user=" + user_id;

    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                    //Hiding the progressbar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}
```

check last item

```
 //This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

any ideas why it works sometimes and why not?

----------------------------> edit

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private final Context context;

    //List to store all posts
    List<Posts> Posts;


    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<Posts> Post, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all
        this.Posts = Post;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.posts_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Posts post =  Posts.get(position);
        holder.post = post;

        //Loading image from url
        //imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        //Showing data on the views
        //holder.imageView.setImageUrl(post.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);


        Picasso.with(context).load(post.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);


        holder.textViewName.setText(post.getName());
        holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Posts.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        //Views
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPublisher;
        public Posts post;

        public ImageView ProfilePic;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                //...

            }

        }

    }
}
```

----------------------------------------- edit 2

```
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(String requestCount, String user_id) {
    //Initializing ProgressBar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //Displaying Progressbar
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    requestCount = requestCount + "&user=" + user_id;

    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);
                    //Hiding the progressbar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

//This method will get data from the web api
private void getData() {
    //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount, user_id));
    //Incrementing the request counter
    //requestCount++;
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //Creating the object
        Posts PostObj = new Posts();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Getting json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding data to the object
            PostObj.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            PostObj.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
            PostObj.setPublisher(json.getString(Config.TAG_PUBLISHER));

            requestCount = PostObj.setId(json.getString(Config.TAG_ID));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adding object to the list
        listPosts.add(PostObj);
    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Is the recyclerview in a activity or a fragment ?

Comment: @Cochi it is a activity

Comment: Thx, can you show the piece of code where you update your recycler view adapter ?

Comment: @Cochi sure! I'll add an edit with my adapter

Comment: where give you news fetched item to the adapter ?

Comment: @Cochi in the same activity as the onscrolllistener. edit 2

Comment: @Cochi the strange thing is that when I reduze the image size on image view it works ok. ` <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewHero"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />` if I add a width 100dp it works... but I'd like to fill the screen width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try with ? :

```
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            // instead of findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition
                int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition(); 
                if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: oh, it is working. my pagination is wrong, but I think that is something I need to adjust to get the last post id.

Comment: Great :)


If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.